# Rails - WillPaginate Conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, will-paginate

I'm trying to paginate the `messages` a `group` has.

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
...
def show
...
@message = @group.messages.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end

  <% unless @group.messages.empty? %>
  <table class="messages" summary="Messages from Group">
  <tr>
  <td class="messages">
  <span class="content"><%= messages.content%></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
  Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(messages.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <%= will_paginate @messagess%>
 <%end %>
```

But when I try to open my `group#show` page, gives me the error: `undefined method 'content' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x31a67f0>`, but the line the error gives is the line where I create a new `Message`, that is in the `group#show` page as well:

```
 <%= f.text_area :content, :rows=>5 , :cols=>49 %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the messages and print each one out individually.

Controller:

```
def show
  @messages = @group.messages.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

View:

```
<% unless @messages.empty? %>
  <table class="messages" summary="Messages from Group">

    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="messages">
          <span class="content"><%= message.content %></span>
          <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(message.created_at) %> ago.
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

  </table>
  <%= will_paginate @messagess%>
<% end %>
```

To prevent the error on your form you will need to pass it a single instance of a message. e.g.

```
form_for(Message.new) do
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My form for the message is `<% form_for(:message, :url => messages_path(:person_id => current_person.id, :group_id => @group.id)) do |f| %>`
How can I put it to end the conflict?

Comment: Swap the `:message` for `Message.new`.

Comment: Thanks! Really worked out. I have a random question: If I put a message with too many characters it won't break the line and respect my table, classes,td divs and stuff, no matter what I use. Any idea on how to sort this?

Comment: Either look at Rails' `truncate` helper, or use the CSS `overflow` property.